# How to get HiddenField control in Masterpage and set it's value?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `MasterPage` that contains a hidden field control. I want to get the current value of the hidden field and set the value of it from pages that use the `MasterPage`.

I have the following code so far: (in one of the pages)

```
   //Get the textbox and set it's value
   TextBox txt1 = new TextBox();
                txt1 = (TextBox)this.Master.FindControl("txtHiddenField");
                txt1 .Text = "true";
```

The above code does not seem to work. What code would I need to get the hidden field control and set it's value? (and get it's value)

Comment: is txtHiddenField a HiddenField? then use HiddenField type. You don't need to use a constructor at all, why should I create an instance to get a reference to another instance?

Comment: I guess it should be as ((TextBox)this.Master.FindControl("txtHiddenField")).Text = "True";

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend to provide a public property/method in your `MasterPage`, that you can use to set/get the HiddenField's value.

in your Master(assuming it's type is called `SiteMaster`):

```
public String HiddenValue { 
    get{return txtHiddenField.Value;}
    set{txtHiddenField.Value = value;}
}
```

In your page:

```
SiteMaster master = (SiteMaster)Page.Master;
master.HiddenValue = "true";
```

This approach is straight-forward, less prone to errors and easily readable. You could even change the control in your master without needing to change the pages(f.e. if you want to replace the hidden-field with a TextBox).

Assuming that your `"true"` value indicates that you actually want to store a boolean, i would recommend to use a `bool` as data-type for the property and a self-explanatory name. Then you can store it in the hiddenfield but the client(the page) does not need to know.

Answer (score 2):

HiddenField sets its text as VALUE, while TextBox has a TEXT property. Of course casting one to the other and setting text property won't help.

Do this instead:

```
HiddenField hiddenField = (HiddenField)Master.FindControl("txtHiddenField");
hiddenField.Value = "true";
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to find the field. hiddenField = null. What reasons could there be for this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have added hidden field control like this ->>

```
<input type="hidden" ID="hiddenFieldID" runat="server" />
```

you can access it like -->>

```
HtmlInputHidden hiddenfield = (HtmlInputHidden)this.Master.FindControl(
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you are missing `ContentPlaceHolder`

Try something like this

```
  ContentPlaceHolder mpContentPlaceHolder;
    TextBox mpTextBox;
    mpContentPlaceHolder = 
      (ContentPlaceHolder)Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");
    if(mpContentPlaceHolder != null)
    {
        mpTextBox = 
            (TextBox) mpContentPlaceHolder.FindControl("TextBox1");
        if(mpTextBox != null)
        {
            mpTextBox.Text = "TextBox found!";
        }
    }
```

Read more about [Reference ASP.NET Master Page Content](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xxwa0ff0.aspx)